# Do we say "People are cheering" to express people lift up their glasses to drink?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-request

> **cheers** (exclamation): ​a word that people say to each other as they lift up their glasses to drink

**cheers** is an exclamation, but

**can we use it to express people lift up their glasses to drink?**

For example, "**People are cheering**"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the correct expression would be "people are toasting", or, more likely, "people are making a toast".